# I don't want drf ValidationError response to be textual. How to do that?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework. How do I change the DRF `ValidationError` detail not to be textual?
For example:

```
raise  ValidationError(detail={"something": True})
```

response:

```
{
    "something": "True"
}
```

expected response:

```
{
    "something": true
}
```

Comment: What happens if you have `detail={"some_thing": "true"}`?

Comment: this is not the thing i want. for string obviously it returns string form.

Comment: And does it work if you try something like `detail=json.dumps({"something": True})`?

Comment: no it does not work obviously cause does not matter what type I pass to it. It changes it to string.

Comment: Your expected response is in JSON format. What are you doing with that response? Where are you viewing it?

Comment: `json.dumps` will turn `True` into JS bool `true` and it wont change to string. I would suggest to keep it like that and not to convert types all the time.

Comment: there is a misunderstanding. I dont provide 'True' for this class. class changes True to that. so json.dumps wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `rest_framework/exceptions.py`:

```
class ValidationError(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    default_detail = _('Invalid input.')
    default_code = 'invalid'

    def __init__(self, detail=None, code=None):
        if detail is None:
            detail = self.default_detail
        if code is None:
            code = self.default_code

        # For validation failures, we may collect many errors together,
        # so the details should always be coerced to a list if not already.
        if not isinstance(detail, dict) and not isinstance(detail, list):
            detail = [detail]

        self.detail = _get_error_details(detail, code)
```

As you can see function `_get_error_details(detail, code)` gets called to manipulate your detail:

```
def _get_error_details(data, default_code=None):
    """
    Descend into a nested data structure, forcing any
    lazy translation strings or strings into `ErrorDetail`.
    """
    if isinstance(data, list):
        ret = [
            _get_error_details(item, default_code) for item in data
        ]
        if isinstance(data, ReturnList):
            return ReturnList(ret, serializer=data.serializer)
        return ret
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        ret = {
            key: _get_error_details(value, default_code)
            for key, value in data.items()
        }
        if isinstance(data, ReturnDict):
            return ReturnDict(ret, serializer=data.serializer)
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        return ret

    text = force_text(data)
    code = getattr(data, 'code', default_code)
    return ErrorDetail(text, code)
```

This is where your boolean becomes string (`text = force_text(data)` part).
One way to overcome this is to overwrite the `ValidationError` class with `self.detail = detail` instead of `self.detail = _get_error_details(detail, code)`. Although I wouldnt suggest doing this and just sticking with the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was a bit late and i got how to get what i want. but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MiladKhodabandehloo how to do it then, without overriding DRF.ValidationError behavior?